# The request failed with HTTP status 503: DNS Fail

Tags: search

I have a host named site collection and on the host file I have 127.0.0.1 pointing to that host name.

I created the search service application but when I try to crawl I get this error:

> The crawler could not communicate with the server. Check that the
>   server is available and that the firewall access is configured
>   correctly. If the repository was temporarily unavailable, an
>   incremental crawl will fix this error. ( Error from SharePoint site:
>   HttpStatusCode ServiceUnavailable The request failed with HTTP status
>   503: DNS Fail.; SearchID = 79904609-8252-4DF4-B240-CB489C002CAD )

I checked IE settings on the server and there is no proxy setup.

Any idea how should I fix this crawling

Comment: Is there SSL in use?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is if that web application has a **root site collection**. Check these sources: [1 (Technet)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx#section2b) and [2 (wictorwilen.se)](http://www.wictorwilen.se/clearing-up-the-confusion-with-host-named-site-collections-and-path-based-site-collections).

Then, if sites are `https`-protected, I'd double **check trusts** if custom CA is used.